# NGRX if the data changes on the API?

Tags: angular, ngrx

The scenario: I have an API that holds a list of products.

UserA connects to my web app and the list of products are cached in UserA's store -> productsState, then sets loaded to true as not to download again on other routes that display products.

UserB connects; the same happens, but UserB can edit productsState (upload new products) and does so.

But UserA's productsState will remain the same?

I was wondering what the best practice, to get UserA's productsState to refresh

Comment: Timeout the data (simple) and use etag, get notify (websocket) to invalidate/update data.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, when you say timeout, are you suggesting, I check data every n seconds and if changed, update UserA's state?

Comment: No avoid checking every n seconds. Just check if the data are older than n seconds and then check the server

Comment: ok thanks, I don't totally understand, as never used etag, but will look into it, do you know any good resources that cover this type of scenario?

Comment: I wrote about this in [NgRx: data synchronization in multiple clients](https://itnext.io/ngrx-data-synchronization-in-multiple-clients-df07785c0188). Without going to much in details, here are the options that I discussed: - Real-time messaging - Refresh client-side - Locking (this isn't refreshing the data but locking forms) - Versioning (this isn't refreshing the data either but preventing an update action if you have stale data)

Comment: Thanks that was helpful and will get me started